TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading ‘queue’) in React 19 with Concurrent Form Submissions
I’m working on a React 19 project and encountering an issue when submitting a form multiple times in quick succession. Specifically, I’m getting the following error after a few consecutive submissions:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'queue')
Here’s a simplified version of my setup to reproduce the issue:

React 19

function App() {
  const formAction = async () => {
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
  };

  return (
    <form action={formAction}>
      <input type="text" name="name" />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}

export default App;

Steps to reproduce:

Enter “1” in the text field.
Submit the form.
While the action is still pending (within 3 seconds), submit the form again.

Expected behavior:
The form fields should be reset after submission.
Actual behavior:
The page breaks with the error mentioned above.
Additional context:

I’ve tested this in a minimal CodeSandbox environment, which you can
view here.
This issue seems related to handling concurrent form submissions and async operations in React 19.

I’ve searched for similar issues but haven’t found a relevant solution. Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
